# How to update two different tables with DetailsView Update Command

Tags: detailsview

I am developing an ASP.NET application in C#.

I have two Database tables **Food(Id, Name, Description)** and **FoodLog(Id, FoodId, FoodName, FoodDescription, ChangedFields, Date)**. As the name indicates, **FoodLog** stores the modification history made by the users to **Food** records and specifies in the **ChangedFields** field which fields have been modified compared with the previous "version" of the record.

To display to the user a specific **Food** record I use the **DetailsView** control. When the user presses the **Update** button an **UpdateCommand** linked to the **SQLDataSource** is executed. This **UpdateCommand** just modifies the corresponing Food record.

In order to add a new record to the **FoodLog** table I need to catch an event fired by the **DetailsView** upon update. When I catch this event I manually compare the record inserted by the user (not yet committed to the DB) with the one in the **Food** table matching its Id in order to keep track of the modified fields and store them in the **ChangeFields** field in the FoodLog table. Now in order to perform this task I can use two events fired by **DetailsView**

- **ItemUpdated**: It is launched after the **UpdateCommand** is executed. This
  way I lose track of the modified fields because the previous
  "version" of the record has been already overwritten.
- **ItemUpdating**: It is launched before the **UpdateCommand** is executed.
  This way I have still the old "version" of the record in the DB and I
  can make the comparison and then dtore in the FoodLog table. However
  if then the UpdateCommand fails for some reason I have a record in
  the log that do not correspond to a change on the Food table.

Anybody might help with this problem? Is it possible to write two different SQL expressions in the **UpdateCommand**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use a stored procedure for your updates.

Call the stored procedure first when you store the old values in log table and then update the main table. Use transaction to avoid partial update in case an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you could just **strong text** use the sp to generate updating and merging and only use an event .NET. If you could just use the sp to generate updating and merging and only use an event .NET invoking the sp